# up-to-date simple OpenGL ES tutorial / template for iOS

Tags: ios, opengl-es

At the moment i can draw a route on a map.
On the map i can zoom and i can pan. If the route is very big it goes really slow.
Therefor i want to do it with OpenGl.

[image: route on island]

From the map i can convert coordinateToPixel and get the current zoom.
I thought it would be the best to base the translation and zoom on that for the transformation matrix.

I never worked with OpenGL before. I have been reading stuff for the last few hours but most stuff i read is outdated or goes into things i don't care about for now like shaders.

Can someone provide me with resources for simple stuff like on the image?

Comment: Nothing you're showing on the map is "really simple stuff." You're looking at drawing vector paths, texturing polygonal areas, drawing overlays, etc. and doing so with a variable scale factor. I doubt you'll find an example of this out there, and it will most likely take a lot of work to reproduce what you're getting for free from Core Graphics and Core Animation right now.

Answer (score 0):

> I never worked with OpenGL before.

You are asking a lot, and I do mean a *lot*, of work from yourself if you want to switch from using native iOS drawing methods to using an advanced real-time rendering system that you don't even know yet.

I agree with Brad Larson that you are going to go much further and faster by leveraging the tools in iOS for your purpose. However, that does not mean you can't improve performance while using them.

I have found that when using Core Graphics for complicated drawing, you can *dramatically* reduce the time it takes to render a drawing by drawing it on a background thread. And Apple makes it much much easier to learn and use [Grand Central Dispatch](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html) than the time it would take you to do all of this in OpenGL.

I learned how to use dispatch queues also for the single purpose of making drawing go faster. The simple technique is to render in the background, then take the results to the main thread for displaying them. Since you already have your drawing code figured out, you won't have to do much extra work to take this extra step, and I think you will be impressed with the performance.

I saw an improvement of at least 5 - 10 times in drawing speed when I implemented Core Graphics drawing with dispatch queues. They are really awesome.